# SQL-injection - is this (oneliner) safe?

Tags: php, mysql, security, sql-injection

PHP:

```
$SQL = "SELECT goodies FROM stash WHERE secret='" .  
    str_replace("'",'',$_POST['secret']) .  
"'";
```

Could an evil genius hacker inject SQL into my SELECT - How ?

Comment: You can still get an invalid statement when the value contains a `\ ` at the end that will escape the closing `'`.

Comment: +1: Interesting question. But regardless of whether it is proven safe or not, I still wouldn't recommend it. :)

Comment: An error is OK - as long as it doesn't affect honest users.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've had a think about this for a while and I can't see any way to inject SQL into this statement.

An SQL string that starts with a single quotes terminates at the next single quote unless it is escaped with a backslash or another quote (`\'` or `''`). Since you are removing all single quotes there cannot be a doubled quote. If you escape the closing quote you will get an error, but no SQL injection.

However this method has a number of drawbacks:

- Single quotes in the input are ignored.
- Backslashes in the input aren't handled correctly - they will be treated as escape codes.
- You get an error if the last character is a backslash.
- If you later extend the query to add a second parameter, it *would* allow an SQL injection attack.

For example:

```
$SQL = "SELECT goodies FROM stash WHERE secret='" .  
    str_replace("'",'',$_POST['secret']) .  
"' AND secret2 = '" .
    str_replace("'",'',$_POST['secret2']) .  
"'";
```

When called with parameters `\` and `OR 1 = 1 --` would result in:

```
SELECT goodies FROM stash WHERE secret='\' AND secret2=' OR 1 = 1 -- '
```

Which MySQL would see as something like this:

```
SELECT goodies FROM stash WHERE secret='...' OR 1 = 1
```

Even if it's impossible to cause an injection in this case the drawbacks make this unsuitable for a general purpose way to avoid SQL injection.

The solution, as already pointed out, is to use a prepared statement. This is the most reliable way to prevent SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Oops, I do that (a lot!). But exchanging the str_replace with mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['secret']) would cure it (AND the possibility of causing an error) ?

Comment: @T4NK3R: Do what a lot? There is a very rare case where mysql_real_escape_string doesn't work properly: http://ilia.ws/archives/103-mysql_real_escape_string-versus-Prepared-Statements.html. Prepared statements is the best way, but  mysql_real_escape_string should work too if done correctly.

Comment: Do: add extra key=value pairs (mostly integers though "hardened" by simple (int) casts). BTW: my php-source is in UTF-8 and the dbConnection also (mysql_set_charset('utf8',$dbCon);)
- Off to read your link now!

Comment: @T4NK3R: If you have two strings in the same query and you're using the str_replace method both times then it's unsafe as I have demonstrated. If using mysql_real_escape_string the attack I showed above is not possible.

Comment: @Mark Byers: Right, that was scarry reading, but wouldn't have affected me, and the vulberability is fixed now, anyway : )
- Your answer get's my green checkmark. But thanks to all participating!

Answer (score 15):

Why won't you use mysql_real_escape_string() or even better - prepared statements? Your solution seems silly.

Comment: seconded... especially for prepared statements

Comment: Then use a lean prepared statement. Filtering just doesn't work; use parameter binding *always*.

Comment: I'm building the statement dynamically (for a search with lots of options), so I'd rather keep each key-value pair together, by building the statement into one string as I go along. Still, 6 votes in 15 minutes.. Getting sweaty palms..

Comment: @T4NK3R: is `str_replace` that much leaner than `mysql_real_escape_string`?  Use the proper tool for the job -- `str_replace` is a half-assed replacement.

Comment: Even if you generate the query dynamically, you can still bind to its parameters instead of relying on an ad-hoc encoding technique.

Comment: A prepared statement will break my back (lots of fancy short-circuiting with date-parameters) - I need it to be in a single string to keep my sanity. So, I'll just exchange  the str_replace() with a  mysql_real_escape_string(). - Is everybody happy with that ?

Comment: @T4NK3R: I'm not, but we can't risk your sanity further.

Answer (score 0):

May be.
The best way is:

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT goodies FROM stash WHERE secret='%s'",
addcslashes(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['secret']),'%_'));
```

Comment: You don’t need to escape `%` and `_` as you’re not using `LIKE`.

Comment: Yes, addcslashes function is optional

Comment: I'm building the statement dynamically (for a search with lots of options), so I'd rather keep each key-value pair together, by building the statement into one string as I go along.

Answer (score -1):

Why just don't use `mysql_escape_string`? And yes, he could, adding `"` instead of `'` and plus, this query will give you an error, I guess.

Comment: I would think that the query `SELECT goodies FROM stash WHERE secret='"'` is no problem. The double-quote won't end the string. What sort of an error are you referring to?